# API code giving me a 4040 error

Tags: api, http-status-code-404

I am trying to create a link for making a Google review for my business. It asks to use my API, but when I attach the API with the corresponding code, it gives me a 404 error.

Here are their instructions:

1. Go to the Google Places API.
2. Enter your business information in the “Enter a location” field at the top of the map.
3. Click your business name in the list that appears. 
   Your Place ID will appear on the map, beneath your business name.
4. Add your Place ID to the following URL to create your link:

https:// search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=

Using the example above, the URL with the Place ID added would be:

https://  search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=ChIJj61dQgK6j4AR4GeTYWZsKWw

When I add my URL to this: https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=EiUyNzg4IFNvdXRoIFN0LCBMaW5jb2xuLCBORSA2ODUwMiwgVVNB

I get a 404 error.

I am not tech savvy, but I am doing my best to understand this. What am I doing wrong?